# Pandas data frame: plotting average for comma separated strings

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

In my dataset I have a column with Topics which are strings separated by coma.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stats': [3377, 1843, 15234], 'Topics': ["A, B, C, D", "A, B", "C, D"]})
```

[image]

What I need is to plot average Stats per Topic (A,B,C,D). Something like this:

[image]

Could anyone suggest a smart way of doing it?

Comment: So the value for 'A' would be (3377 + 1843) / 2 or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your desired output is, but this should hopefully get you going in the right direction.  Key point is to split out the topics, and then you can do whatever analytics you want.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(row.Stats, topic.strip()) 
                    for _, row in df.iterrows() 
                    for topic in row.Topics.split(',')], 
                   columns=['Stats', 'Topic'])
>>> df2.groupby('Topic').Stats.mean()
Topic
A    2610.0
B    2610.0
C    9305.5
D    9305.5
Name: Stats, dtype: float64

>>> df2.head()
   Stats Topic
0   3377     A
1   3377     B
2   3377     C
3   3377     D
4   1843     A
```

Comment: Somehow, I had never encountered nested loops in the form of list comprehensions until your answer (`[c for x in xs for x in y]`). A reference for anyone else discovering this neat feature: https://spapas.github.io/2016/04/27/python-nested-list-comprehensions/

Comment: Thank you very much. All plotted beautifully!